# Any ways to display lolcat output in Vim?

Tags: command-line

I known `lolcat` for a while now, and wondered if it was possible to display the text that it output, inside of Vim correctly.

So i tried:

```
:%! lolcat
```

But while it update the buffer, the text doesn't seem to change at all (compared to when i use it on the commandline, like with `echo "hello world" | lolcat`)

Any reason why this doesn't work in Vim? And maybe any ways to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing is that `lolcat` knows how to add colors when writing to a terminal, so by default it will only add colors when it knows it's doing that. When you run `lolcat` from Vim, it's actually writing to a pipe instead. You can force it to add the colors by using `lolcat -f` (for `--force`) instead.

But then, what you'll see is that `lolcat` is actually adding colors by producing output that includes escape sequences that a terminal recognizes as commands to change colors. Vim doesn't really interpret those by default, and will show them literally, these will look like sequences of `^[[37;41m` or `^[[0m` etc.

In order to have Vim actually interpret these sequences and render those as colors, you can use a plug-in. For example, install plug-in [`chrisbra/Colorizer`](https://github.com/chrisbra/Colorizer) and use the command `:ColorHighlight` after you have the `lolcat -f` output with the escape sequences in your buffer.

Comment: Interesting to see that's how it color the text (using terminal sequences as you mentioned). I tried doing `echo "hello world" | lolcat | hd` but noticed no difference in the hex code with/without lolcat...I guess the terminal sequences are discarded, which would explain why they don't appear in `hd` output?

Comment: @Nordine That's exactly the same thing. If you use `lolcat | some other command` it will not be connected to a terminal, but to a pipe... Use `-f` and it should work: `echo "hello world" | lolcat -f | hd`.

Comment: you're right! works with `-f` :)